# Solution file opens up precompiled code in Inetpub

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a folder that contains ASPX code and its codebehind (C#) as well as a solution file.  The compiled version of the application resides in the `inetpub` directory.

Whenever I open the solution in Visual Studio, VS warns me that it is attempting to open a precompiled website and asks me if I want to continue.  If I click NO it does nothing, but If I click yes it shows me the  ASPX files in the `inetpub` directory.

How do I make the solution work with that code in the directory that it is in (ie with the aspx and codebehind)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this solution was created by going to File->Open->Web Site and then saved afterward.  In orther words, this is not the original solution file.

I suggest simply creating a new solution.  Add the exisitng .csproj if appropriate (ie, you have a Web Application Project), or the existing web site from the directory your code is in.

Answer (score 0):

Before you open your solution try opening your .sln file in Notepad or some other editor and double check that your web site path is right.

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/Url..."
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Physical Path from the solution file\"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\this might be the same as your physical path?\"
```